# Google Spreadsheet, select range from activecell

Tags: range, spreadsheet

I am new to google spreadsheets and i fail finding the answer to my question. I want to cut an range (from the active cell, 5 cells to the right) and  paste it on the other sheet.

I know now that to reference to the currrently active cell you have to use .getCurrentCell

```
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getCurrentCell();
```

I want to write a script that selects the activecell and the next 5 cells on the right. Therefore you could use

```
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,1,5);
```

Problem is, I can't put the range (currentCell) in the getRange

Then I want to cut them and transport them to another sheet. Therefore I could use

```
   var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
   var lastrow = sheet2.getLastRow() + 1;           
   sheet2.getRange(lastrow, 1).setValue('Jan');
```

Problem is, I can't put the range in de setValue

Is there anyone who could help me out (suggestions, directions, no complete code) here?

Thanks in advance, Jan

Answer (score 0):

I figured something out, but wonder if it could be more efficient.

```
function copyOffsetFromCurrentCellPaste() 
{
   var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
   var lastrow = sheet1.getLastRow() + 1;

   var currentcell = SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell();
   var row =  currentcell.getRow();
   var rownumbers = 1
   var column = currentcell.getColumn();
   var columnnumbers = 5

   var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, column, 
   rownumbers, columnnumbers).getValues();
   sheet1.getRange(lastrow, 1, 1, 5).setValues(values);
}
```